# Microsoft Information Protection exception : 'An inactive label was specified'

Tags: exception, sdk, label, azure-information-protection, microsoft-information-protection

When using the MIP SDK, I send a

> SetLabel(MyLabelGuid)

call.
When the argument is one of my Azure Information Protection sensitivity labels GUID.
As a result I get the following exception :

> Microsoft.InformationProtection.Exceptions.BadInputException: 'An
>   inactive label was specified, correlationId:...

As far as I know, there is no identification of a label as "Active/Inactive" at the Azure Information Protection -> Labels blade nor at label properties.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the label is deleted. 
For backward compatible, if the label is deleted, it doesn't really deleted but getting "inactive" - so you can still GetLabel of the old label, but cannot set it.